# What is the relation between edges in a dependency graph and the program call to create a vertex?

Tags: terminology, dependencies, graph, dependency-management, make

A Makefile is a representation of a depency graph. The files are the vertices, for example `somefunctions.h`, `somefunctions.c` and `myprogram.c` are the "input" vertices (is there a formal word for this?) and `somefunctions.o` and `myprogram` are the "output" vertices (again, correct word?).

Then the edges of that graph are somehow related to invocation of the compiler and linker in this example. But not one-to-one, since `myprogram` would have three edges connected to it (`somefunctions.o`, `somefunctions.h` and `myprogram.c`), but only one call to the compiler to create `myprogram`. What would be the correct way to describe that relation?

Answer (score 2):

Your build-dependency graph just maps the path of change propagation and not the build process:

[image]

To map the build process, you’d need to add intermediary build-nodes that are target of the dependency-edges, and add build-edge from the intermediary build-node to the  corresponding target-node.    The build-edges correspond exactly to the build commands of your makefile:

[image]

Comment: I notice that there's one build command node for every output node.

Comment: @user253751 I don't have the makefile of question,  but the idea here is that every orange node corresponds to a makefile target, that creates an output.  Of course, if no myprogram.o is used there, you'd remove the corresponding intermediary orange and green nodes which would not appear in the makefile

Comment: Hm, I guess that makes sense. But now I have two different types of vertices, and the graph also becomes larger. I was hoping to avoid that, but maybe that's not possible.

Comment: @Psirus visually, you could reduce the build-nodes to a point, and remove the arrow head for dependencies: the diagram would appear more compact, and the dependencies and build-edges combined would look as Y shaped arrows.